# Recording audio without noise

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder, mobile-devices, noise-reduction

I'm developing a call recorder with android studio. I use the code below to capture sound:

```
myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_WB);
```

I have a problem: in some devices there's very strong noise (sound is inaudible) and in some devices sound quality is not a problem. How can I solve or get around this problem?

Comment: First you should isolate the problem. Is it the raw recording (i.e. device microphone is noisy) or is it because of the encoding you're applying (conversion to `AMR`)? If it's the 2nd, try a different output. If it's the first, your only solution might be filtering the signal somehow.